# Compare two lists to find the new elements, the removed elements and the existing elements

Tags: javascript

I have two lists of strings like that:

```
let previous_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b7ae97cc6d75e1331e28d9c", "5b7a0c207fab2722a2081caf"];
let current_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b83e3b4412f370bd7b9a05d"];
```

I would like to compare all the elements of the two lists in order to know which one is still in the list, which one is new and which one has been deleted.

The result would be:

```
delete_id = ["5b7ae97cc6d75e1331e28d9c", "5b7a0c207fab2722a2081caf"];
new_id = ["5b83e3b4412f370bd7b9a05d"];
existing_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04"];
```

Is there any function to do so?

I would like to avoid to do two loops with several if conditions like this:

```
let previous_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b7ae97cc6d75e1331e28d9c", "5b7a0c207fab2722a2081caf"];
let current_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b83e3b4412f370bd7b9a05d"];

delete_id = [];
new_id = [];
existing_id = [];

for(let item of previous_id){
   let index = current_id.indexOf(item);
   if(index == -1){
       delete_id.push(item);
   } else {
       existing_id.push(item);
   }
}

for(let item of current_id){
   let index = previous_id.indexOf(item);
   if(index == -1){
      new_id.push(item);
   }
}


console.log(delete_id)
console.log(new_id)
console.log(existing_id)
```

Comment: Are those actually sets? If they are, then the mathematical terms for them are [intersection and difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Implementing_basic_set_operations). If they are not, then this can get very tricky because the elements are ordered and not unique, and you will have to take them into account.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  Your own attempt is important.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I update the post with real value

Comment: @PierBJX The question is whether the order is important or not. Can there be duplicates? Do you care about the order?

Comment: The order is not important and it's not possible to have duplicate @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: @PierBJX In that case it's basic set operations.

Comment: I think you can use filter() + indexOf() + includes() for this :))

Comment: @gforce301 I tried see the post

Comment: @ScottSauyet see my attempt

Comment: @PierBJX See answer. Basically you should not be using `.indexOf` and `.filter` because your input is a set. Set lookups is an O(1) operation while list lookup is an O(n) operation.

Comment: @PierBJX: got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build your array operations atop set ones.  Since there are not supposed to be duplicates, this is the correct structure for internal calculations.  I don't know why `Set.prototype` does not have on it at least `union`, `intersection`, and `difference`, but it's quite trivial to write them yourself.

```js
// Set operations

const intersection = (set1, set2) => new Set([...set1].filter(x => set2.has(x)))
const difference = (set1, set2) => new Set([...set1].filter(x => !set2.has(x)))


// Array operations, builtt using the set ones
// NB: Arrays are NOT Sets, and there is some information lost in the conversion.
// But Sets are the proper data structure for unordered collections of unique values.

const intersectionA = (arr1, arr2) =>  Array.from(intersection(new Set(arr1), new Set(arr2)))
const differenceA = (arr1, arr2) => Array.from(difference(new Set(arr1), new Set(arr2)))


// Main code

const breakdown = (prev, curr) => ({
  delete_id: differenceA(prev, curr),
  new_id: differenceA(curr, prev),
  existing_id: intersectionA(prev, curr)
})

let previous_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b7ae97cc6d75e1331e28d9c", "5b7a0c207fab2722a2081caf"];
let current_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b83e3b4412f370bd7b9a05d"];

console.log(breakdown(previous_id, current_id))
```

If your objection to multiple loops has to do with code bloat, then this might help.  If you think multiple loops is a performance bottleneck in your app (you have tested this, right?), then this won't help at all, as it loops separately for each output you want and  there is additional work on the conversion between arrays and sets.  But I would be quite surprised if these caused any serious bottleneck in an application.

Answer (score 1):

Basic set operations should work:

```js
// Copied directly from MDN
function intersection(setA, setB) {
    var _intersection = new Set();
    for (var elem of setB) {
        if (setA.has(elem)) {
            _intersection.add(elem);
        }
    }
    return _intersection;
}

function difference(setA, setB) {
    var _difference = new Set(setA);
    for (var elem of setB) {
        _difference.delete(elem);
    }
    return _difference;
}


let previous_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b7ae97cc6d75e1331e28d9c", "5b7a0c207fab2722a2081caf"],
    current_id = ["5b7b5498ab3f510e307e7d04", "5b83e3b4412f370bd7b9a05d"],
    previous_set = new Set(previous_id),
    current_set = new Set(current_id),

    // perform set operations on the two sets
    existing_ids = intersection(previous_set, current_set),
    deleted_ids = difference(previous_set, current_set),
    new_ids = difference(current_set, previous_set);
    
console.log("Existing ids: ", Array.from(existing_ids));
console.log("Deleted ids: ", Array.from(deleted_ids));
console.log("New ids: ", Array.from(new_ids));
```

Set operations are more efficient than list operations, so you should use a set whenever it makes sense.